# Extracting text from number of webpages list in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet with around 800 links to different web pages.
Each page has text which I need to extract.
I used the importxml in Google sheets for doing the same but for 800 entries it's not loading.

Please provide other option available either in Excel or python.

For example, in the link 
http://access.cesc.co.in/misdtr/fd/dtr_llgis.php?txtdistnm=02&txtdtrnm=0200112
is in "A1" cell of Excel sheet

I would like to extract the text

```
"A K PAUL RD.( C ) P/T"
```

in Excel in B1

similar types of links in

A2, A3 and so on.

in Excel I use `=webservice(A1)` and after that `=filterxml(A1,"/b")` but error.

Comment: First of all **you** need to decide which language and programs you want to use. We cannot provide solutions, because this is no free code writing service. • Also you will need to show what you have researched and tried so far and include your code in your question. See [ask] and [mcve]. We can assist you to fix/improve your own code, but we cannot write the code for you.

Comment: Python or in Excel

Comment: **You** must decide which one to use! Start writing your code and if you get stuck or errors come back [edit] your question and include your code. We cannot write code for you, we can just assist you to fix yours.

Comment: in Excel I use =webservice(A1) and after that =filterxml(A1,"/b") but error.

Comment: "Python or in Excel" so, make either a post with either the [tag:vba] or [tag:python] tag and add the code you tried, don't make a post with three different languages in the hopes someone will just make you a working code.

Comment: @AritraSarkar My suggestion is to google for *"web scraping with VBA and Internet Explorer"* to find some good tutorial and give it a try yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @peh...

Answer (score 2):

If all your links are in an Excel sheet, you could extract them with [xlrd](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to have a Python list, i.e. `["http://link1", "http://link2"]`

Then you could use fetch the webpages using [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) to get the corresponding HTML texts, i.e. `""" <b>A K PAUL RD.( C ) P/T</b> """`

Finally, you could parse the obtainded HTML texts with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) so that you get the value you want, i.e `A K PAUL RD.( C ) P/T`.

This is the workflow, if you have a more detailed question, feel free to explain the part which seems unclear to you, or ask another question.